# create right type for constructItem function

Tags: typescript

I can't find out the reason why this type doesn't work. How to write the right type for `constructItem`?

`constructItem` should also be able to execute without param. In that case, it returns "Item" without any index/number. It strictly has to return string literal as I wrote not generic string.

```
type Item = <T extends number>(
  index: T | undefined,
) => T extends number ? `Item ${number}` : 'Item';

const constructItem: Item = (index) =>
  typeof index === 'number' ? `Item ${Number(index) + 1}` : 'Item';
```

I tried to do it this way also but I get same compiler error

```
const constructItem: Item = (index) => index !== undefined ? `Item ${Number(index) + 1}` : 'Item';
```

The compiler error on `constructItem` is

```
Type '`Item ${number}` | "Item"' is not assignable to type 'T extends number ? `Item ${number}` : "Item"'.
  Type '`Item ${number}`' is not assignable to type 'T extends number ? `Item ${number}` : "Item"'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot derive and validate what type will get returned depending on the parameters and the logic of your function implementation. Hence, the use of a generic type `Item` will not suffice.

You have two potential ways to tackle this problem:

1. [Function Overloading](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading):

```
function myFunc(): 'Item';
function myFunc(index: number): `Item ${number}`;
function myFunc(index?: number): string | number {
    return typeof index === 'number' ? `Item ${index}` : 'Item';
}

const constructItem = myFunc;
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQBQEoBciA5AJJQCmyRA3AFCiSwIoZbYxgAm5AHoWCGQAjcgCcCiAAZlKiACQBvAcLEBfSXQbR4SNJkjsuvAPz9BI8YQDOUURwDmiAD6JlFxAtqJviUeSggokhQqAAO5HDAiBzcPIgAvInEbmJEiMZSMsjyCjG86oiEpBRUdKq0tBAINohVYDaiINBZCSz6EHRAA).

2. [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type ReturnItem<T> = T extends number ? `Item ${number}` : 'Item';

const constructItem = <T extends number,>(index?: T): ReturnItem<T> =>
  (typeof index === 'number' ? `Item ${Number(index) + 1}` : 'Item') as ReturnItem<T>;
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AksCBbAPAFQD4oBeKPKCAD0xQBMBnKFBLAIwiSgH4oADDbFAAkAb2ZsOAX15QAXFADkArAoDcAKHUBjAPYp6wKLv3AkCLcGUko%20CtQh1G49kgA0BABQBLOlS7y8AEp5OERUZXwiYgJ1KCgPUEgdADMoH1oqEmJSBWcOBW4%20K1EAORYXb19KQKgAaigARmk5RWUFGoBDRlDkdExcQlUgA).

Comment: Then I will take function overloading approach. Tnx